# Need clarification on flow of android debugger connect protocol over network

Tags: linux, networking, android, adb

We have Android 7.1 booted on qemu kind of virtual platform. We are trying to connect ADB debugger over network. The platform uses slirp for communication between virtual platform and the host. We have bound port 5585 on android running on virtual platform to port 15585 on host.

Once Android is booted, using terminal on Android device, we are setting adb port to 5585 as below,
$ stop adbd
$ setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5585
$ start adbd

We are using one more machine on which Android SDK is running. We are issuing following command on Android machine,
adb tcpip 15585
adb connect :15585

When we analyzed packet captured on virtual platform hosting Android, we observe that we are getting request for ADB connect on port 5585 but stack on Android is not able to communicate back to the connect request.
From Android platform, we are seeing ARP requests are going out to resolve IP address of machine which initiated connect request, but it is not getting any response.

My question is, whether Android daemon will not respond till ARP request response is not got? or daemon can still respond to the connect request without ARP request not getting response?